# What is the color of caution or warning of hazard sign?

Tags: traffic

Is the following caution or warning of hazard sign orange or yellow? My impression is that it's color yellow, but the [link](https://www.alberta.ca/sign-shapes-and-colours.aspx) says it's color orange. And even though the aforementioned link says caution or warning of hazard sign only has one color, in this other [link](https://www.alberta.ca/warning-signs.aspx) there is more than one color (yellow, green). In addition, there is more than just one shape (diamond shape, rectangular). Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about the law.

Comment: @bdb484 in the US, the colors of signs are regulated by the Uniform Manual of Traffic Control Devices and signage which fails to conform to these requirements could form the basis of a legal defense that insufficient signage was provided. Therefore, I recommend this remain open.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The link implies the OP is asking about Canada, which does not have a uniform standard. (See Quebec)

Comment: @user71659 that suggests then that there are multiple appropriate answers for Canada then. The link in particular seemed to cite Alberta, so if I'd the expertise I'd respond for that part of Canada. Regardless, I think it's disingenuous to suggest the question isn't about law as the color of traffic signs is regulated in many places.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I'd agree that a question about what color a sign should be would be on topic. But this is just a question about whether a shape's color has been identified correctly.

Comment: I actually debated answering because I had some of the same thoughts.  Plus the regulatory meat of any sign is really in the text or symbol depicted.  However, if different responses were required of drivers on the basis of color alone this misidentification would definitely have legal ramifications.  For that reason it is at least relevant, even if off topic.

Comment: In the following link there is more than one color (yellow, green). In addition, there is more than just one shape (diamond shape, rectangular). https://www.alberta.ca/warning-signs.aspx. So a diver would respond incorrectly if he/she didn't see the second link, that is if the content of the first link is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The picture you posted is of a yellow sign mislabeled as orange.**

While some tints can be distorted depending on computer screens and color settings and individual perceptions may vary, verification of this specific example can be made by the context provided in your link.

Below you can see the published example of a construction area sign:

[image]

Several places below that is the one you posted in your question:

[image]

As you can clearly see the colors are distinctly different, yet the color description is the same.  It's apparent that the graphic artist who created this copied their work and changed the color, but forgot to change the text.  *Trust your eyes!*

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your explanations!

Comment: [Trusting your eyes](https://bestnsight.com/blog/so-what-colors-can-colorblind-people-see/) may not work in all cases: "People who have protanopia also may see orange and green as just yellow, depending on the shade."

Comment: @PeterM, I'm not a doctor and clearly didn't mean to imply that those with a visual affliction should trust their eyes, only that if one is able to differentiate between these two colors that they shouldn't presume that the text is instead correct.

Comment: @MichaelHall I understand.  But then I had this idea that there could be corner cases for your aphorism.  And I was surprised to find that there are actually would have an issue with the colors.